# C++ string input inside loop

Tags: c++, string, input

I have the following C++ code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    string text;
    string text2;
    int len1, len2,len3;
    while(t--) {

        getline(cin,text); //first string input
        set<char> s(text.begin(),text.end());
        len1=s.size();

        getline(cin,text2); //second string input
        set<char> s2(text2.begin(),text2.end());
        len2=s2.size();
        len3=len1+len2;
        s.insert(s2.begin(),s2.end());
        len1=s.size();
        if(len1<len3){
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm running this program it seems that the first string input is not being taken properly. The second input is working fine. The program is only taking input of t and text2, but not text1. What's the problem actually?

Note: The program is working as expected when I remove the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the use of `cin >>` and `getline`. I suggest using `getline` for all interactive user input.

To read an `int` using `getline` without error checking, you can do something like:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
int t = stoi(line);
```

The problem is that when `cin >> t` reads an integer, it reads *only* the integer and leaves the next character (a newline) in the input buffer. This newline is read by the next call to `getline`, which leads to confusion about the operation of your program.

Comment: An example will make things more clear.